# Input-group-append bugs when on mobile (lower resolution screens)

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have a form on a navbar where I want to display the submit button appended to my text-box.
When on higher resolution screens (not mobile), it works as I expect:

[image]

But when I'm on mobile there is a gap between the text-box and the submit button like this:

[image]

In some pages, where I have more inputs on the search bar the gap gets even worse.

My code is very simple, as you can see:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Item", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "form-id", @class = "navbar-form" }))
    {
        <span class="form-group">
            <span class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Buscar..." name="qsearch" id="qsearch" value=@auxQsearch />
                <span class="input-group-append input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </span>
            .
            .
            .
        </span>
        .
        .
        .
    }
</nav>
```

I'm not editing these classes on my CSS file.
Front-end is kinda new for me, and I couldn't find a solution for this, so I'm very lost about what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

This problem was in a property in my CSS that went unnoticed by me when I was looking for a solution.

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

What was happening is that, on mobile, the form would be broken into two rows. Then, the text input would try to expand itself to fill the whole row, but it was limited by those 280px, while the button wouldn't do anything about its width.
Removing the max-width for the text input made it work exactly as I wanted.

[image]